# Vistas mysql en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, vistas

Puedo utilizar llamar tabla vista con el modelo en laravel? Que tan buena practica es? o es preferible llamarla con el selector DB?

Ejemplo = vusers / Model: User

Comment: explica por favor mejor tu pregunta, añade un ejemplo con un mínimo de código legible y entendible, con vistas te refieres a vistas generadas desde mysql? o vistas blade por favor considera mejorar tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas que buena mala/práctica diría que es una decisión de diseño en la arquitectura de la aplicación, laravel (eloquent) va a tratar la vista como una tabla.

Especial consideración hay que tener en cómo se arma la vista para permitir `updates` e `inserts` ver: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html

En ambientes donde varias aplicaciones usan una misma base suele ser conveniente definir vistas parciales para por ejemplo delegar filtrado por roles al motor de base de datos.

### Un ejemplo clásico:

(*) aplicación que sólo interactua con usuarios "estudiantes"

```
CREATE VIEW estudiantes AS 
  SELECT * FROM usuarios 
  WHERE rol='estudiante' 
  ORDER BY id;
```

Al no usar funciones de agregación o grupo la vista es "updateable" y se comporta como una tabla normal asi que:

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Estudiante extends Model {
    protected $table = 'estudiantes';
 }
```

Te permite luego usarlo onda:

```
 <?php

  use App\Estudiante;

  $estudiantes = App\Estudiante::all();

  foreach ($estudiantes as $estudiante) :
    echo $estudiante->nombre;
  endforeach;
```

En caso de no usar una vista tendrías que usar explicitamente el filtrar por rol, algo asi:

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Usuario extends Model {
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
 }
```

Y deriva en:

```
 <?php

  use App\Usuario;

  $estudiantes = App\Usuario::where('rol', 'estudiante');

  foreach ($estudiantes as $estudiante) :
    echo $estudiante->nombre;
  endforeach;
```

Del lado de la aplicación te evitas tener que validar el rol (que al fin y al cabo sólo es para estudiantes y no administradores por ejemplo), y del lado del motor de base de datos le das mas trabajo en lo que sabe hacer bien y te permite poner retricciones extra, por ejemplo `WHERE rol='estudiante' AND tienetodopago='SI'` con lo cual la aplicación ya recibe datos filtrados.

Nota: lo armé de memoria asi que puede haber algun pifie, pero básicamente si, podes usar views como tables en los models (ver las restricciones de insertar y modificar)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero estas contribuyendo a agregar información de "baja calidad" al sitio. Hay que sugerir al OP modifique su pregunta, revisar [ask] para que conozcas como debe estar estructurada una pregunta.